# Load NetStream content without playing

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

How can I set netstream to load the file only and not playing. Only play when I request it to do so?

Example code:

```
private var nc:NetConnection;
private var ns:NetStream;

// Connections
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
ns.client = this;

// Screen
video = new Video();
video.attachNetStream(ns);
addChild(video);
ns.play("file path");
```

When the `ns.play()` is called, it will load and play the video. How can I have it get ready with video only and play only when I requested it to do so?

Thank you.